# npm install change package-lock.json with VSCode differently that with terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I work with a coworker on a Node.js project. At each commit, even if not any dependencies were added, we have differences in `package-lock.json`.

The only difference is I use npm with a Ubuntu terminal, and he uses the embedded VSCode terminal. We use the same npm and Node.js version.

When I generate the package-lock.json my dependencies will be like this :

```
"jsonify": {
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "bundled": true,
    "optional": true
 }
```

And when he will generate it will obtain :

```
"jsonify": {
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "bundled": true,
    "dev": true,
    "optional": true
}
```

So the only difference is that `"dev":true`. When I use VSCode terminal I obtain the same result. Can anyone explain that behaviour ?